ラズパイpico wをMacのVSCodeでCMakeで開発しているのですが、ヘッダファイル内でincludeエラーが出てしまいます
ラズパイpico wをMacのVSCodeでCMakeで開発しています。
Cのコード内でエラーは表示されないのですが、ヘッダファイル（opt.h）内でincludeエラーが出てしまいます。
エラーを消してビルドし、uf2ファイルを作成したいです。
どなたかご教示いただければ幸いです。
ヘッダファイルのパスは以下のとおりです。
Users/UserName/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/include/lwip/opt.h
opt.hのエラー箇所です。
#include "lwipopts.h"

エラー内容です。
lwipopts.h: No such file or directory

書いたCMakeListを載せておきます。プロジェクトの中にはCのコードは一つであり、CMakeListも同じ階層にあります。
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# Set the path to your Pico SDK installation directory
#set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/Users/reiya/pico/pico-sdk" CACHE PATH "Path to the Pico SDK")

set(PICO_BOARD pico_w)

include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(tcp_client_pico_w C CXX ASM)

# Initialize the Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

# Add executable
add_executable(tcp_client
    tcp_client.c
)

# Include directories
target_include_directories(tcp_client PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(tcp_client
    pico_stdlib
    pico_cyw43_arch_lwip_threadsafe_background
    lwip/sockets
)

# Enable USB output, disable UART output
pico_enable_stdio_usb(tcp_client 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(tcp_client 0)

# Create map/bin/hex file etc.
pico_add_extra_outputs(tcp_client)


こんな記事あたりが関係してそうですが。Raspberry Pi picowでsocket APIを使う, Pi Pico W でWi-Fi 通信をやってみる（2）
